# Работа с графическим элементом Path в приложении UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

В UWP для графического элемента Path можно в разметке XAML загружать описание пути в виде текстовой строки в Data, например:

```
<Path Stroke="DarkGoldenRod" StrokeThickness="3"
    Data="M 100,200 C 100,25 400,350 400,175 H 280"/>
```

Подскажите, возможно ли загружать описание пути в виде текстовой строки при программном создании элемента Path? Если да, то пример как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

[@Nicolas Séveno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9658042/nicolas-s%C3%A9veno) на en.SO [предлагает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53867204/451518) вариант через [`XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlbindinghelper.convertvalue#Windows_UI_Xaml_Markup_XamlBindingHelper_ConvertValue_Windows_UI_Xaml_Interop_TypeName_System_Object_):

```
_path.Data = (Geometry)XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(Geometry), "M 100,200 C 100,25 400,350 400,175 H 280");
```

Смотрите [Is there a way to parse a vector path geometry in UWP in code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880793/is-there-a-way-to-parse-a-vector-path-geometry-in-uwp-in-code-behind)